# HTTP method wrapping an external service while building an API

Tags: api, rest, http, design-patterns, software-design

I'm designing an API. With this API, my users will be able to update Stripe subscriptions, my APIs will wrap Stripe calls in order to perform these actions. The thing is Stripe uses the POST method to update entities. I was asking myself, what should I do in this case? What are the best practises for wrapping these kind of external services? Should I use a PATCH method(This is how I started writing the API) or just do as Stripe and use the POST verb?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you wish to present your API to the public.

[HTTP Verbs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) (or request methods) can add some clarification to your API if the method names are difficult to understand.

Good naming of API methods could void the use case of HTTP verbs.

All of that said, if you API performs actions that do not fall within the typical classification of a get, post, put, delete or patch request, then where do you go from there?

In summary, there is no correct or incorrect answer for your use case. It is more of a personal preference.